# Objective c pagecontrol background color

Tags: objective-c, uicolor, uipagecontrol

I have a scrollview with a pagecontrol, when i change her color, my pagecontrol dissapear.

```
UIColor *col = [UIColor colorWithRed:14.5 green:35.6 blue:72.9 alpha:1];
        self.pageControl.backgroundColor = col;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UIColor *col = [UIColor colorWithRed:14.5 green:35.6 blue:72.9 alpha:1];

If you have the RGB ASCII values 0 to 255

you can specify it as

UIColor *col = [UIColor colorWithRed:(255/255) green:(0/255) blue:(0/255) alpha:1]; // This represent Red color

Answer (score 1):

The RGB values are supposed to be between 0 and 1. (See [the docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html)). So you're setting the background color to fully opaque white here.